# How to retopology the model with out losing the detail?

Tags: retopology

I'm a beginner at blender and I try to retopology my sculpted model by using QuadRemesh. But the retopology model loses a lot of detail. I try to use shrinkwrap and multiresolution but it will make my model have a ton of triangles. It makes it hard to do texturing and rigging. Does any way can lower the triangles but keep as many as possible details?[image]

Comment: You can first try a Ctrl E > Un-Subdivide, and check the values in the Operator box, you'll probably need to make some corrections though, if this doesn't work you'll probably need to retopologize manually, that's why you should always keep a low-poly version (if you began with a low-poly version of course)

Comment: The QuadRemesh is a good addon. It should have an adaptive remesh option so it adds more details where it is needed and less where it is not needed. But if this character is your main character and *not* a background character or one in a crowd then I would do a manual retopology to get proper edge loops. They are important for facial expressions. Blender Studio offers [stylized base meshes for free](https://studio.blender.org/training/stylized-character-workflow/base-meshes/).

Comment: Helpful videos about retopology: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn3ukorJv4vs8PQj8z_PMbZAVLFEhQF5L and https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLL3OEv6vd5VA4owAPOI0QdCcEmvl1f3BT. Blender Studio also has live streams about the creation of their character "Snow": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXhIz-5g3Gc. Snow you can get here: https://studio.blender.org/characters/

Comment: If I gonna make an animation and two main characters in it. What is the limit of polygons/triangles for each character?

Comment: The limit is how many polygons your computer can handle ;-) Your goal is to have as few polygons as possible and to get the shape and details you want at the same time. A full-character model often has 20k to 30k vertices. You can bake normal maps for skin and cloth details. If you add a subdivision modifier with (1-2 levels) the model can have 100k or more vertices. But while you create the animation you can turn off the modifier to get the best performance in the viewport. This way you don't have to worry about the polycount. Keep in mind the environment also requires polys & they can sum up